# save user input data in multiple page php form

Tags: php, mysql, session, save

I have a multiple page form in PHP. I also created a login page in which username and passwords are stored in a session(I used [this tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL)). Now, I am a bit confused about these things:

1. I would like to enable user to fill the form from the last saved session (e.g., in case of computer or browser crash, failed internet connection, etc., he will not rewrite all the data he previously inserted).
2. Also, I am not sure about how to store data inserted by each user in Mysql table. Is it OK if I just insert all users answers into one table (Let's say "Answers") with these fields: Unique_Id, UserId, question 1, question 2, ... )? Or, it might be better to insert data from each table into a separate table with the same design, for example, table 1: (userId, q1, q2,.., q5), table 2: (userId, q6,q7,..q10) and so on.

This is the code for one of the form pages (Page2, other pages are similar)

```
<?php
session_start();

 // Checking first page values for empty,If it finds any blank field then redirected to first page.
 if (isset($_POST['submit1'])){
 if (empty($_POST['q1'])
 || empty($_POST['q2'])
 || empty($_POST['q5'])
 || empty($_POST['q6'])){

 // Setting error message
  $_SESSION['error'] = "Mandatory field(s) are missing, Please fill it again";
  header("location: page1.php"); // Redirecting to first page 
  } else {

   foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
       if (is_array($_POST[$key])){
            $_SESSION['post'][$key] = implode(',', $_POST[$key]);
         }
       else{
            $_SESSION['post'][$key] = $value;
        }
   }
  }
  } else {
  if (empty($_SESSION['error_page2'])) {
  header("location: page1.php");// Redirecting to first page.
  }
 }
?> 

<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media=screen>

<style>
.error {
 color: #FF0000;

 }
</style>

</head>

<body>
 <div id="show">   

<span id="error">
<!---Initializing Session for errors-->
<?php
if (!empty($_SESSION['error_page2'])) {
 echo $_SESSION['error_page2'];
 unset($_SESSION['error_page2']);
 }
 ?>
 </span>

 <form id="form2" action="page3.php" method="post">

<div class="meter"><span style="width: 40%">Step 2</span></div>
<fieldset id = "Form_Questions"> 
<fieldset id = "q8"> <legend class="Q8"></legend>
<label class="question"> What are your favourite genres of movies?<span>*</span></label>
<div class="fieldset content"> 

<style type="text/css">
.checkbox-grid li {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 25%;
margin-bottom:5px; 
}     
</style>

<title>Survey Form</title>
 <meta http-equiv="content-Type" content="text/html: charset=UTF-8" /
 <ul class="checkbox-grid">
<li><input type="checkbox" name="q8[]" value="Action"><label for="checkgenre[]">Action</label><span></span></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="q8[]" value="Adventure"><label for="checkgenre[]">Adventure</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="q8[]" value="Comedy"><label for="checkgenre[]">Comedy</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="q8[]" value="Animation"><label for="checkgenre[]">Animation</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="q8[]" value="Drama"><label for="checkgenre[]">Drama</label></li> 

 </ul>
</div>
</fieldset>
 //REST OF QUESTIONS
  .....
   ....
<input class="mainForm" type="submit" name="continue" value="Save and Continue" />  

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull answers for a question from a previous visit then it will just be a case of doing a SELECT query on the database to determine what they had entered or leave blank if they have not entered an answer before.

Cannot work out exactly what you mean by storing all in the session but you might be better storing answers in cookies if you want to save all the answers in one go at the end.

To make your web page dynamic you could store all questions and answers in the database.  You could use a layout like...

```
Table name: 'Questions'
  ID               int (autonumber)
  Question         text

Table name: 'Answers'
  ID               int (autonumber)
  QuestionID       int
  Answer           varchar(250)

Table name: 'UsersAnswers'
  ID               int (autonumber)
  UserID           int
  AnswerID         int
```

(this is assuming all your questions are going to be multiple choice answers)

Doing something line this will allow you to add as many questions as you like without having to add extra columns to tables.

**Edit...**

If you wanted dynamic answers then you could just store the answers in a table such as...

```
Table name: 'UsersAnswers'
  ID               int (autonumber)
  UserID           int
  QuestionID       int
  Answer           string
```

This table will allow you to store an answer to a question answered by a user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as u said this assumes that questions are all multiple choice.. but I have some questions which are text (autocompletion), or dropbox of countries... Do you have any idea about how to store these answers in answer table???